# retrieve ajax posted values in servlet?

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

```
var schedule = [];

var data = { 
   'user_id' : '12', 
   'day_of_week' : 'Monday',
    'when' : 'start',
    'modified' : 'true'
 }

schedule.push(data);
var data = { 
   'user_id' : '13', 
   'day_of_week' : 'Tuesday',
    'when' : 'end',
    'modified' : 'false'
 }
schedule.push(data);
// schedule would have two objects in it
```

I am posting array to servlet using jquery ajax post request as below .

```
data :  {'myData':schedule},
url :"./myController",
```

Now how can I get array of objects and literate to get all the values? Each array object has   string, long and boolean type values. How can I get all the values by  iterating?

Comment: Why didn't you bother to explore the `request.getParameterMap()` to see in which key/value format the data has been arrived?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One strategy is to use JSON to pass this kind of data back and forth server and client.

On the client side, convert the array of schedule into JSON string by using stringify function. Send that via AJAX:

e.g.

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(schedule);
```

Your AJAX object will do the following:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "./myController",
  data: {'schedules':jsonData}
});
```

Now on the server side use a JSON parser like google's GSON library.

In your servlet do the following:

```
String jsonData = request.getParamater("schedules");
```

Parse it using GSON

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<Schedule> schedules = gson.parseJson(jsonData, List<Schedule>.toClass());
```

You can create a schedule class which will map JavaScript object to Java object

I can provide a better code which is tested if interested ... I do not have access to IDE at the moment ... however I hope you get a general idea